# perl File::Copy does not work

Tags: file-copying

I tried to use File::Copy or just shell cp. None worked. Any clue?

https://github.com/songyangster/perltest

```
$ bin/test_copy.pl from_dir to_dir
Failed to File::Copy cp from_dir/foo1.txt to to_dir
cp: from_dir/foo1.txt: No such file or directory
Failed to cp from_dir/foo1.txt to to_dir
Failed to File::Copy cp from_dir/subdir1/foo2.txt to to_dir
cp: from_dir/subdir1/foo2.txt: No such file or directory
Failed to cp from_dir/subdir1/foo2.txt to to_dir
```

Comment: The error is very clear, one of the paths/files doesn't exist

Comment: I would not have asked the question if the paths/files did not exist.  They are, after all, found by File::Find